# Can't find classes from imported java project in dynamic web project

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I'm working on a Dynamic web project (REST service) which imports a java project I've made earlier. Now I'm trying by adding the project to the build path to use classes from the java project. While writing this it gives no Errors but on runtime the service gives the folowing error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/pathname] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Controller/Generator] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Controller.Generator
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem from the error and given context?
Otherwise i could upload the project for further debugging.

The project runs on Tomcat 7.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not compile time, rather runtime while class loading. Some quick points to debug...

1. If you are generating a WAR/ EAR from your web project, make sure your java project is added a .jar utility inside WEB-INF/lib in the installed application(folders may vary based on the web/ application server you are using).
2. If you are using an IDE for deployment(e.g. Eclipse), make sure your java projects are properly 'Project Referenced' by visiting the 'Property' tab of your web project. You can also use this java project as a shared library and made corresponding configurations from your server admin console and based on the server you are using, it may vary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I indeed forgot to add the project.jar to my lib.
Now of to fixing the next problem but I wil first give that a try myself :)

Comment: Sure. Please put a comment with updates and I hope you should REST in peace :)

Comment: Project is running propperly by now, had to remake all the REST at one point because i used some crappy tutorial that was mostly wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm suposing you are using ANT to compile your project (An eclipse ANT projet). Right-Click your project, select 'Deployment Assembly' and then Add option to select the project you want to make a reference.

Comment: The dynamic web project runs on a tomcat 7 server not an ANT project, should have said so in the question wil be editing.